# Como dou permissão ao usuário para acessar uma página no Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

Me deparei com o seguinte erro, onde no mesmo diz que o usuário não tem permissão para acessar a página:

> Error 403
>
> You are not allowed to access this page.

Por gentileza, alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se a pagina que deseja accesar é como este:
`localhost/app/index.php?r=usuario/admin`,
então deves buscar o arquivo `/app/protected/controllers/UsuarioController.php`
e dentro desta buscar a função `accessRules()` e modificar e/ou aumentar o seguinte

```
return array(
        ...,
        array(
            'allow',    //  aqui estas permitindo algo
            'actions' => array('admin','admin2'),    //  aqui dizes que algo (accion) queres permitir podes colocar cuantas queiras 
            'users' => array('admin'),  //  aqui dizes quem tem permisao para ver esta "pagina"
        ),
        array('deny',
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
        ...,
    );
```

Nesta página vais encontrar mais informações sobre [`accessRules`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/pt_br/topics.auth#sec-2).

Comment: beleza @vandro muito obrigado pela ajuda :)

Comment: Galera foi falha minha pois nao sabia que tinha que logar no gii para executar a app... obrigado a todos

Answer (score 0):

Esse erro certamente é causado pelo [mecanismo de filtragem de IP](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAccessControlFilter) que *Gii* utiliza para proteger o sistema contra intrusos, por padrão é permitido apenas acessos em *localhost*, a usuários remotos(*que aparentemente inclui você*) o acesso é negado.

Para contornar isso, é preciso editar o arquivo de configuração principal na seção de módulos para *Gii*, e editar o *array*, [`ipFilters`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/GiiModule#ipFilters-detail), para incluir o seu IP.

```
// protected/config/main.php
return array(
    ...
    'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'class'     => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'  => 'Senha',
            'ipFilters' => array('127.0.0.1', '192.168.1.7'), // Adicione o seu IP aqui
        ),
...
```

A propriedade `ipFilters` pode incluir tantos items que você deseje, podem ser endereços IP ou curingas, como `192.168.1.*`. Se você deseja permitir que todos os endereços acessem tal página, você pode mudar para falso a propriedade:

```
'ipFilters' => false
```

Porém vale lembrar, como dito na [documentação](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/GiiModule#ipFilters-detail):

> Se você quiser permitir que todos os IPs para acessar gii, você pode definir essa propriedade para ser falso (**NÃO FAÇA ISSO se você não sabe a conseqüência!**) O valor padrão é array ('127 .0.0.1 ',' :: 1 '), o que significa GiiModule só pode ser acessado no localhost.